# Migrating abstract XML beans to @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I'm migrating my project's spring XML configuration to @Configuration class and I'm trying to figure out how should I handle `bean` tags with `abstract="true"` property. Something like:

```
<bean id="factoryTemplate" class="com.template.FactoryTemplate" abstract="true">
  <constructor-arg index="1" ref="resizerFactory"/>
  <constructor-arg index="2" ref="metricFactory"/>
  <constructor-arg index="3" ref="settingsDao"/>
</bean>
```

**Clarification**: I can't change the XML where the abstract bean is defined because I'm part of a larger project and I'm changing only my modules.

Is there a methodology on how should I do such migration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bean definition inheritance with annotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266175/bean-definition-inheritance-with-annotations)