# Bean inheritance via annotation

Tags: java, spring

How I can provide bean inheritance in Spring using annotations? In XML config I used `<parent="parentBean">` tag. Is there some annotation?

For example, I have two beans(cacheEventLogger extends fileEventLogger):

```
 <bean id="fileEventLogger" class="com.myuspring.core.loggers.FileEventLogger" init-method="init">
    <constructor-arg value="d:/1.txt"/>
</bean>


<bean id="cacheEventLogger" class="com.myspring.core.loggers.CacheFileEventLogger" init-method="init"
      parent="fileEventLogger" >
    <constructor-arg value="15"/>
    <property name="cacheSize" value="2"/>
```

I've create AppConfig class:

```
@Configuration
```

public class AppConfig {

```
@Bean(initMethod = "init")
public FileEventLogger fileEventLogger() {
    return new FileEventLogger("d:/1.txt");
}

@Bean(initMethod = "init")
public CacheFileEventLogger cacheFileEventLogger() {
   ???

}
```

}

What annotation should I set to cacheEventLogger for extending fileEventLogger?

Comment: You can't dependency inject a base class; it's not a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Spring annotations doesn't have an equivalent of spring XML `parent` tag/attribute. There is a workaround specified in the JIRA with some custom coding.

Refer to the related spring JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5580 and a reference to stackoverflow answer from this JIRA [Bean definition inheritance with annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266175/bean-definition-inheritance-with-annotations/23266686#23266686)

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yep, this is it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no such `parent` property for the Spring-specific annotations, because the Java language provides everything needed (i.e inheritance, abstraction) to create a *template* and use it as a *parent* for some Spring-beans.

Comment: You mean, class of child bean must extend class of parent bean? As I know, in xml-config bean inheritance != class inheritance

Comment: Yes, but you since you have the Java inheritance, you could achieve the same template-based structures