# JavaConfig Spring Inheritance

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, javabeans, spring-java-config

So I have a class structure like so:

```
public class A {
    private String foo;

    protected A() {};

    protected A(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B() {};

    public String getSomething(String test) {
        return super.getFoo() + test;
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    public C() {};

    public String getSomethingElse(String test) {
        return super.getFoo() + test;
    }
}
```

Here are my java configuration files:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigA {
    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A("FinalString");
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigChildren {
    @Bean
    public B b() {
        return new B();
    }

    @Bean
    public C c() {
        return new C();
    }
}
```

Obviously the problem is that the `super` value is the child classes are null so doing `super.getFoo` will be null even though the configuration is initialized.

I'm wondering how to connect these two in the configuration. I know in spring XML there's a way to do it with the `parent` field but I don't know how to do that in java config.

I tried playing around with singletons but I don't think that's really applicable or good practice here. Is there a way to initialize `A` for the child classes without passing the string variable into every child and having it do `super(foo)`. Or is that the only way to do it?

Comment: Your code won't compile at the moment. Do you have a parameterless constructor in `A` in your actual code?

Comment: @Pillar no my code compiles, it has the same constructor as above. I want to initialize it with the string value i pass in like i do above in the config class. And I want all the child classes to have access to that string.

Comment: Your code above will not compile because `B` and `C` aren't invoking the only constructor in `A` which takes an argument.

Comment: @Pillar sorry i added the default constructor.....i guess now that i'm typing it out it seems im gonna have to pass in the string to every child class and have them do `super(stringFoo)`?

Comment: Pretty much. Or, if that string value is meant to be a default value, your parameterless constructor can set it itself.

Comment: @Pillar well that string is read in by spring from the `application.properties` file. So I guess I'll just pass it in. I just don't like length constructors.....

Comment: @Richard If you are looking for `parent` attribute equivalent, it is not supported with `annotations`. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199294/bean-inheritance-via-annotation/35199917#35199917