# Spring Batch - How to set RunIdIncrementer globally using JavaConfig

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jobs, spring-java-config

im developing a Project using Spring Batch and JavaConfig (no XML).
I am creating Jobs using an Autowired [jobBuilderFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/JobBuilderFactory.html).

is it somehow possible to set the Incrementer for the Factory globally ?

return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobName").incrementer(**new RunIdIncrementer**()).start(stepOne()).next(lastStep()).build();

sorry if this is a dump question but i am new to Spring Batch and did not find a working solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "setting the Incrementer for the Factory globally?" The incrementer is something related to a particular job, it increments the job parameters when you run the next instance of the job. So each job has its own incrementer. You said you did not find a working solution, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: when i look at the spring batch samples the job definition looks like this:
`return jobs.get("myJob").start(step1).next(step2).build();`
And it seems as if there is no incrementer set (sorry if i am wrong).
We will only use the basic "RunIdIncrementer" in the whole batch Project and thats why i wanted to set it globally for all jobs.
We trigger the jobs via Cron + Rest (with dummy parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XML config you would use [bean definition inheritance](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-child-bean-definitions), but you said you don't use XML.

Since there is no equivalent of XML bean definition inheritance with Java config (See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23266686/5019386), you can create the `RunIdIncrementer` globally in your config and use it in job definitions:

```
public JobParametersIncrementer jobParametersIncrementer() {
    return new RunIdIncrementer();
}

public JobBuilder getJobBuilder(String jobName) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get(jobName)
            .incrementer(jobParametersIncrementer());
}

@Bean
public Job job1() {
    return getJobBuilder("job1")
            .start(step())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job job2() {
    return getJobBuilder("job2")
            .start(step())
            .build();
}
```

But again and as said in comments, you will end up having `run.id` values that are not consecutive for each job.

Comment: Thank you ! It seems as if a new RunIdIncrementer instance for each Job seems to be a "cleaner" solution especially with the consecutive values.

Comment: exactly, that's the point of my first comment. The `RunIdIncrementer` is related to a particular job.