# How can I configure job and step inheritance in spring batch using spring builders?

Tags: java, spring-boot, inheritance, spring-batch

I have some spring batch jobs that the most of the configuration are the same and have some small changes like the query or item reader.
I saw some job and step inheritance using Xml config like [this](https://ozenero.com/use-spring-batch-inheritance-function) , but I'm looking for similar functionality using spring batch configs E.G, (jobBuilderFactory and StepBuilderFactory).
Heare is my job config:

```
@Bean
public Job job() 
{
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .start(master())
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .build();
}
```

and this is one of steps:

```
@Bean
public Step workerStep()
{
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("workerStep")
            .<Subscription,ProcessorDto>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(reader())
            .writer(writer())
            .processor(processor())
            .faultTolerant()
            .skip(RuntimeException.class)
            .skipLimit(skipLimit)
            .build();
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to the XML bean definition inheritance in the Java configuration style. There is no need for that since one can use the built-in inheritance in Java, see [Bean definition inheritance with annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266175). The `JobBuilderFactory` provided by Spring Batch can be extended to create `JobBuilder`s with common properties, and then the common builder could be used for specific job definitions (same for steps).

You can check [this article](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/06/spring-batch-2-2-javaconfig-part-4-job-inheritance/) which provides more details and code examples of how to achieve that. The credit goes to [@tobias-flohre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2644939/tobias-flohre) for that great blog post series on Spring Batch.

Comment: Thanks. I used java inheritance. moved main configs to BaseJobConfig and all other jobs extends that.